# History of the exponential function and its derivative

Tags: exponential-function, math-history

Who was first to discover that the derivative of the exponential function is the exponential function itself. Can someone recommend me any good resources where I can read and learn more about the history of it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Good candidates are Descartes, Newton, Leibnitz and Euler.

Comment: Perhaps this can be helpful: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:E_(mathematical_constant)

Comment: @YvesDaoust thanks, can you recommend anything particular? Is there some article about who discovered the derivative of the exponential function first?

Comment: Sorry, no, nothing specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most comprehensive reference I know of is

**[1]** Florian Cajori (1859-1930), *History of the exponential and logarithmic concepts* (in 7 parts), **American Mathematical Monthly** 20 #1−7 (January−September 1913),
[pp. 5−14](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2973509), [pp. 35−47](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2974078), [pp. 75−84](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2973441), [pp. 107−117](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2972960), [pp. 148−151](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2972412), [pp. 173−182](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2973069), [pp. 205−210](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2974104). [Links are to freely available copies.]

Keeping in mind that the derivative of an exponential function (with first degree input) is the same as the original exponential function (modulo a multiplicative constant), the following gives a lot of early "realizations" of this notion.

**[2]** Lorenzo Jan Curtis, [*Concept of the exponential law prior to 1900*](https://astro1.panet.utoledo.edu/%7Eljc/explaw1.pdf), **American Journal of Physics** 46 #9 (September 1978), pp. 896−906. [Link is to a freely available copy.]