# Reference books for $e^x$

Tags: reference-request, exponential-function, eulers-number-e

I'm in search of a book in which I can learn about exponential functions.
Is there a good book in which I can learn about the history of $e$ , definition of $e^x$ ?

Comment: What is your Math background / education?

Comment: You can learn the definition in a few sentences.  This would appear as a very small part of a section of a chapter.  Why would you expect there to be a *whole book* on the subject?

Comment: As for the history, again... the history is not so rich and detailed that it should need a whole book dedicated to it like you might find for $\pi$.  Instead, look for any math history book and reference the specific chapter that talks about it.  Just about any comprehensive math history book will give at least some information, so it is hard to make a recommendation here.

Comment: See [History of the exponential function and its derivative](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4102223/13130) AND [$e$: **The Story of a Number**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0691033900) by Eli Maor (1994) AND [*The
number* $e$](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2308112) by Coolidge (1950) AND [*The number* $e$](https://www.jstor.org/stable/301620) by Mitchell/Strain (1936).

Comment: If you know Italian (your name is the same as my grandad), the introductory chapter of an old book of mine (freely available as an ebook) is very simple and it is focused on $e^x$ for the most part (see "La strana coda della serie $n^{n^{\dots}}$" 2011), while a serious historical reference is G. Eisenstein, "Entwicklung von $\alpha^{\alpha^{\dots}}$, J. reine angewandte Math, vol. 28, 1844.
On the other hand, a very very simple introduction to $e^x$ can be found here: https://betterexplained.com/articles/an-intuitive-guide-to-exponential-functions-e/